# Add text annotation to SDC pipeline?

Tags: streamsets

Is it possible to add a text boxes (/annotations) to an SDC pipeline (v3.8.2)?  I want to be able to write a note describing what a few different parts of the pipeline are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fragments if you use streamsets control hub.
And give them a custom names.

https://streamsets.com/documentation/controlhub/3.13.x/onpremhelp/datacollector/UserGuide/Pipeline_Fragments/PipelineFragments_title.html

If you don't use control hub, you can try to use Orchestration stages to call another pipelines.
https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Orchestration_Pipelines/OrchestrationPipelines_Title.html#Orchestrators_Title

So basically split your logic into several pipelines, and create a "orchestration" pipeline that will call them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Not really what I was hoping for (an EASY way to annotate a pipeline), but it seems as close as it gets : /  so marking as answered.